# Asp.Net Boilerplate InsertAsync method not work and return negative id

Tags: ef-core-2.0, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to know which cases entity failed to add and return negative id?

[image]

Comment: Call `_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();`